# Storing multiple textfield inputs

Tags: java

I've been working on project trying to store inputs inside an array via user inputs on the GUI.
The issue right now is I am unable to find something similar to the Scanner method's "input.next".

Thanks for any help that comes by

Here's what the GUI class that gets executed from my Main look like

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;


public class GUI implements ActionListener {

    //Private the variables to make them accessible to other methods
    private static JLabel orderLabel;
    private static JTextField orderText;
    private static JButton confirmButton;

    public  GUI(){
        JFrame window = new JFrame();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        window.setSize(350, 200);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.add(panel);
        window.setTitle("Place your order");

        panel.setLayout(null);


        //Creating label for the order text field:
        orderLabel = new JLabel("Your order:"); //Creates the label memory
        orderLabel.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25); //Creates bounds for the label
        panel.add(orderLabel); //Adds the label to the window


        //Creating the text field
        orderText = new JTextField(); //Creates text field memory
        orderText.setBounds(100, 22, 165, 25); //Creates text field bounds
        orderText.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(orderText); //Adds the text field to the window

        //Creating the button to confirm order
        confirmButton = new JButton("Confirm order");
        confirmButton.setBounds(90, 100, 170, 30);
        confirmButton.addActionListener(this);//Links the button to the action listener method inside this file
        panel.add(confirmButton);



        window.setVisible(true);

    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String input = orderText.getText();
        String temp = input.next();



    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use list.add(input)?

Comment: Instead of trying to create multiple orders in your actionPerformed method, create only one order.  When the user presses the button a second time, your actionPerformed method will be called a second time, which will create a second order.  And so on for the third button press, and the fourth.

Comment: Using `String temp = input.next();` should be done in `list.add(input)`.There are different types of logic about scanner. Example `input=>answer input=>answer` or `gather all input=>answer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the [Scanner#next()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) method against the contents of a **JTextField** then just use a Scanner object to do that, for example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(orderText.getText());
while (input.hasNext()) {
    list.add(input.next());
}
```

Of course you would want everything supplied within the JTextField to be delimited with a whitespace, for example:

```
Bread Milk Sugar Coffee
```

which would play out as a list looking something like this:

```
Bread
Milk
Sugar
Coffee
```

This of course may not be good enough since a lot of required items would contain more than one word, for example:

```
French Fries Whole Wheat Bread 2% Milk
```

which would play out as a list looking something like this:

```
French
Fries
Whole
Wheat
Bread
2%
Milk
```

Not what is really wanted. In this particular case you can use the [Scanner#useDelimiter()](https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-scanner-usedelimiter-method) method to specify the delimiter you plan to use when typing the desired items into the JTextField. So, if you decided to use a semicolon (;) as a delimiter between typed in items and you entered into the JTextField:

```
French Fries; Whole Wheat Bread; 2% Milk
```

The list would look more like:

```
French Fries
Whole Wheat Bread
2% Milk
```

The code would be:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(orderText.getText());
input.useDelimiter("\\s{0,};\\s{0,}");
while (input.hasNext()) {
    list.add(input.next());
}
```

To put this into your (sort of) runnable application:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //Private the variables to make them accessible to other methods
    private static JLabel orderLabel;
    private static JTextField orderText;
    private static JButton confirmButton;

    public GUI() {
        initializeForm();
    }

    private void initializeForm() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(350, 200);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setTitle("Place your order");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);

        //Creating label for the order text field:
        orderLabel = new JLabel("Your order:"); //Creates the label memory
        orderLabel.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25); //Creates bounds for the label
        panel.add(orderLabel); //Adds the label to the window

        //Creating the text field
        orderText = new JTextField(); //Creates text field memory
        orderText.setActionCommand("orderText");
        orderText.setBounds(100, 22, 165, 25); //Creates text field bounds
        orderText.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(orderText); //Adds the text field to the window

        //Creating the button to confirm order
        confirmButton = new JButton("Confirm order");
        confirmButton.setActionCommand("confirmButton");
        confirmButton.setBounds(90, 100, 170, 30);
        confirmButton.addActionListener(this);//Links the button to the action listener method inside this file
        panel.add(confirmButton);
        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI().setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String textToTokenize = orderText.getText().trim();
        // TRY to determine the delimiter used within the JTextField entry
        String delimiter = textToTokenize.replaceAll("[^:;'\"\\|\\\\~!@#$%\\^&\\"
                                                   + "*-_+=<>.?/]", "").trim();        
        if (delimiter.length() == 0) {
            delimiter = " ";
        }
        else {
            delimiter = delimiter.substring(0, 1);
        }
    
        if (!textToTokenize.isEmpty() && 
                    (e.getActionCommand().equals("confirmButton") || 
                    e.getActionCommand().equals("orderText"))) {
            List<String> shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();
            // If you want to use Scanner's next() method then 
            // just use Scanner to do it...
            Scanner input = new Scanner(textToTokenize);
            input.useDelimiter("\\s{0,}" + delimiter + "\\s{0,}");
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                shoppingList.add(input.next());
            }
            // Test...Display list in console window:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html>Supplied shopping list items are:"
                                + "<br><br><center><font color=blue>" + shoppingList.toString()
                                .replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "") + "</font></center><br></html>", 
                                "Supplied List...", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        orderText.setText("");
        orderText.requestFocus();
    }
}
```